# How to convert this mysql query to run on snowflake / mpp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Background**

I am struggling to convert this mysql query to work on an database which does not have variables that can be set at the row level, like you can with mysql.  I'm not sure it's possible to do this without looping, but that's the goal.

**Problem**

We have a customer id `id` and a session timestamp `event_datetime`.

For each customer I need to interpret each session as either valid or invalid according to the following definition:

- a valid session expires after 30 minutes.
- a session is valid if it does not occur during the timeframe of an earlier valid session.

An alternative definition is trivial to compute: a session is valid if it has been 30 minutes since last session.  But that's not what I'm after here.

So for example:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00 <-- valid
2018-01-01 00:15:00 <-- invalid
2018-01-01 00:31:00 <-- valid
2018-01-01 01:14:00 <-- valid
2018-01-01 01:17:00 <-- invalid
2018-01-01 01:25:00 <-- invalid
2018-01-01 01:43:00 <-- invalid
2018-01-01 01:45:00 <-- valid
```

I am just trying to avoid looping.  Use of any analytic / window functions commonly available is fine.  Ultimately I'm trying to implement this on snowflake.

**What I tried**

I have tried to come up with something using window functions, joins, not exists, but struggling to find a solution.  For example, doing a running sum of the session time diffs seemed promising, but I couldn't think of how to get the cumulative sum to reset to zero after reaching 30 minutes.  I know I could order each customer's sessions and loop through (so that max iterations would be max number of sessions for a single customer), but trying to avoid that.

**Sample data and mysql solution**

Below is a solution that uses mysql.  Both definitions are calculated (30-minute-lapse and 30-minute-expiry).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS work.test;
CREATE TABLE work.test (id INT, event_datetime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO work.test
VALUES (123456789, '2017-12-08 15:24:29.297000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-08 15:25:42.510000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-08 15:28:49.023000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 07:23:49.693000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 07:25:03.487000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 07:35:52.613000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 07:45:52.613000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 07:55:52.613000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 08:05:52.613000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 15:55:24.070000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 15:55:57.063000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-10 15:56:37.633000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:00:41.543000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:02:13.187000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:02:47.370000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:03:29.843000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:03:56.667000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:06:12.493000000'),
    (123456789, '2017-12-17 09:07:26.113000000');


SELECT
    @last_session_datetime AS last_session_datetime,
    @diff := timestampdiff(MINUTE, @last_session_datetime, s.event_datetime) AS diff,
    if(@diff IS NULL OR @diff >= 30, 'valid', 'not valid') AS valid_30_minute_lapse,
    @last_visit_datetime := if(@curr_customer_id = s.id AND timestampdiff(MINUTE, @last_visit_datetime, s.event_datetime) < 30, @last_visit_datetime, s.event_datetime) AS last_visit_datetime,
    if(@last_visit_datetime = s.event_datetime, 'valid', 'not valid') AS valid_30_minute_expiration,
    @curr_customer_id := s.id,
    id,
    event_datetime,
    @last_session_datetime := s.event_datetime
FROM work.test s
JOIN (
         SELECT
             @curr_customer_id := 0,
             @last_visit_datetime := '1900-01-01',
             @last_session_datetime := NULL) a
ORDER BY s.id, s.event_datetime
```

In this sample data, session `2017-12-10 07:55:53` would be valid according to 30-minute-expiration, but *not valid* according to 30-minute-lapse.  It was only 10 minutes after the prior session, but over 30 minutes since the last validated session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake's table-valued Javascript UDF capability is perfect for this type of query.  Essentially you can define your own windowing function that tracks the stream of dates in order, and outputs the "valid" vs. "invalid" values based on the prior "valid" value seen.  (Javascript Table Valued UDFs are documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/udf-js-table-functions.html)).

Below is a code sample to do just that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION classify (ts string)
RETURNS table (valid string)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
STRICT
IMMUTABLE
AS '
{


 initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
    validStart = Date.parse("0000-00-00");
 },


 processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
    var thisDate = Date.parse(row.TS);
    var minsDiff = (thisDate - validStart) / (1000 * 60);
    if (minsDiff < 30) {
       rowWriter.writeRow({VALID:  "invalid"});
    }
    else {
       validStart = thisDate;
       rowWriter.writeRow({VALID:  "valid"})
    }

 },


 finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/},

 }
 ';
```

Now you can call this function on every row in your stream as follows... (presumably you want the "valid/invalid" value calculated segmented based on ID groupings):

```
select * from test,  
table(classify(event_datetime::string) 
      over (partition by id order by event_datetime));
```

When run over your sample data, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: You can also make the function more general by adding a second parameter to specify the # minutes defining an interval, and passing it a constant 30 or new value as your session model changes over time...

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would seem to be captured by a `not exists` subquery:

```
select t.*
from work.test t
where not exists (select 1
                  from work.test t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.event_datetime > t.event_datetime - interval '30 minute' nd
                        t2.event_datetime < t.event_datetime
                 );
```

Comment: This misses session `2017-12-10 07:55:53`

Comment: @chorbs . . . No session starts at that time.  It is part of `'2017-12-10 07:35:52.613000000'`.

Comment: 25, 35 and 45 are not valid because they are part of 23... which means that 55 is valid.

Comment: Just to try to clarify, this solution is applying 30-minute-lapse rule, but I was looking for 30-minute-expiration :( Thanks though.